# Using CSS3 3D Transform's rotate3d(x,y,z,rotate), how can I achieve this?

Tags: css, css-transforms

So here's the situation:
`oX` and `oY` are what I have `transform-origin` set to, with a Z coordinate of `0`. I want to be able to rotate around the axis drawn, with an arbitrary origin. How? I don't understand how CSS3's `rotate3D(x,y,z,rotate)` works.

[image: Awfully drawn diagram of 3D plane]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, I had to apply the `perspective()` modifier on the parent container - so that the `rotate3D()` is in the correct context.